# Is it possible to have more than one minimal DFA 's for a regular language?

Tags: finite-automata, minimization

[image]If we create two DFA's for a language L say DFA A and DFA B. Then, after minimising the DFA's we get their corresponding equivalent minimal DFA's . Is It always the case that both minimal DFA's have same number of states?

I designed 2 DFAs for a language containing strings with 1 as their second last symbol. (The alphabet is {0,1}
I made 2 DFA's one has 3 states one Has four. I am unable to minimise any of the two.

Comment: Might be good to show those two DFAs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: @Kelly Bundy. Okay I have modified my question and included Image the two DFA's I made.  I made DFA1 directly using intuition. For the other One I First made an NFA and then used subset construction to convert it into an equivalent DFA.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization the technique I'm using for minimising DFA's

Comment: DFA2 is wrong, doesn't accept "10".

Comment: DFA1 is also wrong, doesn't accept "11".

Answer (score 2):

The minimum deterministic finite automata is unique up to isomorphism.

Isomorphism effectively means "equal shape". With other words, there is only one minimum DFA and you can name the states as you want, this renaming technically creates a new automata, but all of this different possible renaming of the states are isomorphic to each other - the shape is the same, just the representation is different.

Ignoring the isomorphism, the minimum DFA is unique.